# Subtract value row by row in matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I have a 1 column matrix with the following values:

```
*-------*
|   6   |
|   4   |
|   3   |
|   1   |
|   1   |
*-------*
```

With this function, starting from the first value, I subtract the value in the following row and place 0 at the end. This is the result:

```
Delta = Ctv_ds_universal(1:(end-1),1)-Ctv_ds_universal(2:end,1);
Delta(end+1)=0;

*-----------*
|   2 (6-4) |
|   1 (4-3) |
|   2 (3-1) |
|   0 (1-1) |
|   0       |
*-----------*
```

Now, I would like to reverse the order and start subtracting from down to the top, placing 0 at the beginning. How can I modify the function?

```
*------------*
|    0       |
|   -2 (4-6) |
|   -1 (3-4) |
|   -2 (1-3) |
|    0 (1-1) |
*------------*
```

Comment: I think it might be helpful to check the diff() and flip() functions from Matlab. The first takes the difference (you need to add the zero manually at the end) whereas flip() can place a vector in its reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

```
Delta = 0;
Delta = [Delta; Ctv_ds_universal(2:end,1)-Ctv_ds_universal(1:end-1,1)];
```

Comment: Why do you need to define `Delta = 0` first?